# How to Implement Pusher Note for Laravel 5 project.?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

**Hello Laravel vue.js Developers, please help me, i try to implement Laravel note sharing with others by Pusher but when i try to edit the note i cant retrieve my olders on, juste FYI i want to create a note and share it with another user for correction.
Please i have implement this package from this site: https://pusher.com/tutorials/collaborative-note-app-laravel.
Thank you a lot for your help.**

Edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
   @section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

            <edit-note :note="{{ $note }}"></edit-note>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


  @endsection
```

My problem is when i click to edit the note i can't call the EditNote.vue.

Comment: Put the code in the question, please, not as screenshots. We also need details on what's not working - error messages?

Comment: https://pusher.com/tutorials/collaborative-note-app-laravel. I have followed this tutoriel, i made the same thing and when i click on edit note the edit-note in vue js is not called. what code may i share....view or controller or modal.

Comment: You need to describe what's going wrong - what is not working, how specifically, any error messages you get, etc. - and it would be helpful if you replace the screenshots in your post with the actual code, so we can copy/paste and modify it.